# Android Chooser Intent working in AVD but not in real device / unable to find application to perform this action

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery

Chooser Intent is working in AVD but not working in real phone. My phone is samsumg galaxy core. I sent my app to my email and downloaded in my phone and installed. The App is working in the real phone but only the chooser Intent part is not working. Under the chooser intent i have 3 intents one for taking a picture from camera, another for selecting a picture from gallery and another for removing the selected picture from the view. Its showing the message "unable to find application to perform this action" in the Chooser. My code is as below.

Please note that this is working in AVD (emulator) but not working in real phone. What could be the problem ?

```
    ImageButton imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,null);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            Intent removeProfPic = new Intent();

            String mPackage ="com.example.myapp";
            String mClass = mPackage + "." + "RemoveProfilePic";

            removeProfPic.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage, mClass));

            Intent[] intentArray =  {cameraIntent,galleryIntent};

            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose");
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, removeProfPic);

            startActivityForResult(chooser,1);

        }

    });
```

:
:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED && data != null)
    {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri pic_uri = data.getData();

            if(pic_uri !=null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Bitmap picture = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), pic_uri);

                    ImageButton imagebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
                    imagebtn.setImageBitmap(picture);
                    profilePictureSet = true;
                }

                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 

            else 
            {
                Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                String s = b.getString("key1");

                if (s.equals("delete"))
                {
                    ImageButton imagebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
                    imagebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_img);
                    profilePictureSet = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    ImageButton imagebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
                    imagebtn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    profilePictureSet = true;
                }
            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried including the following in Androidmanifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But still not working.. Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance !

I just interchanged galleryIntent and removeProfPic as follows and its working now. Thanks !

```
        :
        Intent[] intentArray =  {cameraIntent,removeProfPic};
        :
        :
        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
        :
```

Comment: This doesn't answer... but why do you have the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE set twice? You don't even need it once, since WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE includes it...

Comment: Thanks! I removed the duplicates. Why this doesn't answer ?

Comment: I searched throughout the net but couldn't get a solution for this... experts pls help..

Comment: Mine wasn't a real answer - just a fix to what jumped into my eyes reading your manifest. You still have your problem.

Comment: See: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: The problem is solved. I gave my removeProfPic intent in the intent array as Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS and gave galleryIntent as Intent.EXTRA_INTENT as follows.. Thanks Vyger

Answer (score 0):

You have not set type of data in intent for ex...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send To"));
```